# Pushing files not staged for commit even after nominally commiting them

Tags: git, gitlab, gitignore

I placed my GitHub `/repo1` repository in a `/all_repos` folder that contains two others and that should become the repository.

Before it looked like that:

```
/repo1
```

Now:

```
/all_repos
     /repo1
     /scraper
     /webapp
```

So I would like to overwrite the original repository with this new architecture. Yet these new directories seem not to be staged for commit despite explicitly `git commit directory -m ...` them:

```
C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   scraper (modified content)
        modified:   webapp (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass>git add scraper

C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass>git commit -m "adding/separating scraper from the rest"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   scraper (modified content)
        modified:   webapp (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass>git commit scraper -m "adding/separating scraper from the rest"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   scraper (modified content)
        modified:   webapp (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass>git push origin master
warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.ifresearch.org/data-science/bass2.git/
Everything up-to-date
```

It produces strange empty folders with an orange color on gitlab:

[image]

**Therefore how can I push files not staged for commit even after nominally committing them?**

Is it because of my `.gitignore`?

```
# Created by https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python,flask
# Edit at https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore?templates=python,flask

### Flask ###
instance/*
!instance/.gitignore
.webassets-cache

### Flask.Python Stack ###
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
pip-wheel-metadata/
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.nox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.py,cover
.hypothesis/
.pytest_cache/
pytestdebug.log

# Translations
*.mo
*.pot

# Django stuff:
*.log
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal

# Flask stuff:
instance/

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/
doc/_build/

# PyBuilder
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# IPython
profile_default/
ipython_config.py

# pyenv
.python-version

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.
#Pipfile.lock

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow
__pypackages__/

# Celery stuff
celerybeat-schedule
celerybeat.pid

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# Environments
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/
pythonenv*

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
.dmypy.json
dmypy.json

# Pyre type checker
.pyre/

# pytype static type analyzer
.pytype/

# profiling data
.prof

### Python ###
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files

# C extensions

# Distribution / packaging

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.

# Installer logs

# Unit test / coverage reports

# Translations

# Django stuff:

# Flask stuff:

# Scrapy stuff:

# Sphinx documentation

# PyBuilder

# Jupyter Notebook

# IPython

# pyenv

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow

# Celery stuff

# SageMath parsed files

# Environments

# Spyder project settings

# Rope project settings

# mkdocs documentation

# mypy

# Pyre type checker

# pytype static type analyzer

# profiling data

# End of https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python,flask

# Security
webapp/security/*
webapp/venv/*

scraper/scr_env/*
scraper/nosetime_scraper/spiders/nosetime_spider.py
scraper/nosetime_scraper/spiders/sephora2.py
```

Comment: You have created *submodules* (perhaps half-assed ones, as you probably did not use `git submodule add` to do it). It is not possible to store a Git repository in a Git repository, for security purposes, so you can't do what you want. You'll have to change what you want, or use submodules.

Comment: @torek thanks. I didn’t knew that. I using a clients gitlab account and I am limited to only one repository. Can’t I reinitialize the git repository with all the stuff I want to use? Otherwise how can I use submodules?

Comment: A submodule is a reference, in one Git repository, to some other Git repostory. If you're literally limited to one Git repository and need to use two or more, that obviously won't work. If you have to have everything in a single repository, you can get the files (and commits if you want multiple *versions* of the files) out of some other Git repositories and use them to build new commits in a new, initially-empty repository. Don't put the *repositories* into the repository; do put the *files* into commits in the new repository.

Comment: Remember that a repository is a large collection of commits, with each commit being a large collection of files plus some structure that remembers that the *previous* commit for commit X is commit W, and so on. If you just need the latest copy of each file, just get one commit out—whichever one has the latest copy.